# lvalue required as left operand of assignment for a macro with arguments

Tags: c, macros, lvalue

I am trying to print a string 'x' numbers of times using macro as arguments with the following code:-

```
 1 #include<string.h>
 2 #include<stdio.h>
 3 #define print(x,c)      while(x>0)\
 4 {\
 5         puts(c);\
 6         printf("\n");\
 7         --x;\
 8 }
 9 
 10 int main()
 11 {
 12         char c[20];
 13         strcpy(c,"Hallelujah");
 14         print(5,c);
 15 }
```

But while compiling, I get the following error:-

```
 macro2.c: In function ‘main’:
 macro2.c:7:2: error: lvalue required as decrement operand 
   --x;\
   ^
 macro2.c:14:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘print’
   print(5,c);
   ^
```

I am unable to figure out the problem, kindly help thank you.

Comment: because you can't do `--5` in c!

Comment: I think you are confusing macros with function calls. `5` is not getting assigned to `x` here.

Answer (score 3):

After marco expansion, this statement

```
print(5,c);
```

becomes

```
while(5>0) { puts(c); printf("\n"); --5; };
```

As you can see, you can't decrement a literal value (`--5`). You need a variable (*a modifible lvalue*) to be able to achieve that. Your marco looks superfluous. You can simply use a loop:

```
int x = 5;

while(x > 0) { 
   puts(c); 
   printf("\n"); 
   --x; 
}
```

If you *really* want to use a macro, then you could do:

```
 #define print(x,c)  do { \
 int t = x; \
 while(t>0) {\
         puts(c);\
         printf("\n");\
         --t;\
 } \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Macros are expanded by the preprocessor and the result is handed over to the compiler.

Your code will be expanded to:

```
 int main()
 {
      char c[20];
      strcpy(c,"Hallelujah");
      while(5>0)
      {
         puts(c);
         printf("\n");
         --5;
      }
  }
```

As you can see, the `x` is replaced with the actual argument expression in each instance. It does not work like in a regular function where the argument variable is a local copy of the expression value.

I suggest that you either convert the macro to a C function or that you declare a variable to hold the value before calling the macro.

The second option would look like this:

```
int n = 5;
print(n,c);
```